# calculate input text in js, html form

Tags: javascript, input

I'm new to Javascript, trying to put together a form that will calculate inputs. I've gotten so far as to get the total value showing but it is showing as 0, and not the total sum of each field that has an input.

I have copied several examples and this is the one that seems to work best

```js
$('.form-group').on('input','.prc',function() {
    var totalSum = 0;
    $('form-group .prc').each(function() {
        var inputVal = $(this).val();
        if($.isNumeric(inputVal)){
            totalSum += parseFloat(inputVal);
        }
    });
    $('#result').text(totalSum);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
    <label>Energy</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control prc"/>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Justice</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control prc"/>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Total</label>
    <output id="result" class="form-control prc"/>
</div>
```

Expected result: the sum should calculate as the numbers are entered. Not all fields need to have an input. The total has to equal 100 and I have not gotten to that part. :)

Comment: please share your code so far, so that we can know how to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the line

```
$('form-group .prc').each(function() {
```

Change that to

```
$('.form-group input.prc').each(function() {
```

There should be a "`.`" in front of form-group, and you should be selecting `input.prc`. Otherwise you will be adding the total back to itself too.

```js
$('.form-group').on('input','.prc',function(event) {
    var totalSum = 0;
    var currentInput = event.target;
                  
    $('.form-group input.prc').each(function() {
        var inputVal = $(this).val();
        if($.isNumeric(inputVal)){
            totalSum += parseFloat(inputVal);

            if (totalSum > 100) {
                totalSum -= currentInput.value;
                currentInput.value = "";                 
            }
        }

    });
    $('#result').text(totalSum);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Energy</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control prc"/>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Justice</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control prc"/>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Total</label>
    <output id="result" class="form-control prc"/>
</div>
<button id="submit-bn">submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: @mlsatya You can use comments (like here, just "add a comment" below) to discuss the issue. See my answer above. Click "Run code snippert" in my answer (not in your question) and see that it will work :)

Comment: @mlsatya says: "The fix works great, however the inputs are not adding correctly. The total is all over the place."

Comment: @mlsatya Please add comments by using the comment section here ("add a comment" below), instead of editing Answers directly.  Please try the code in my answer above. You can do this by clicking the blue "Run code snipper" button in my answer. When I input "Energy" = 2 and "Justice" = 3, I get Total = 5. What are you getting?

Comment: I must have still had a small error in my code. It is working. Thank you

Comment: @mlsatya You're most welcome! If the answer worked for you please consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Yes absolutely I will. Can you by chance help me with one more aspect? I need to make sure that the total adds to 100, not less or more.

Comment: Not sure how we can do that if the user is the one inputting the numbers... Say they input 20 and 30 in the two input fields, it will add to 50, not 100. Unless: say they input 20 in "Energy", then "Justice" automatically adjusts to 80 by itself, and Total stays 100. Is that what you're after?

Comment: No, the way the client wants to have it work, is they can add whole numbers into any field, as long as the total comes to 100. In other words they need to disperse 100% into different categories. It cannot be less than 100 or more.

Comment: Using the above html elements, give examples of how you'd expect this to work. e.g. Example. User keys 40 into "Energy". What do you expect to see in "Justice" and "Total"?

Comment: The total box will show 40, the remainder of the inputs empty. As they key in more it will reach 100, once it hits 100, then they cannot add any more. If it comes under 100, the user will also be notified on 'submit' - to send to the database, that it needs to add to 100.

Comment: I'm using php post to send to mysql.

Comment: @mlsatya Ok I've added code so that totals cannot be more than 100. If more than 100, the previous input is removed. Good luck!